# How do I configure an environment for rebuilding current (Mantic) kernel packages?

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm trying to build a patched version of the current Mantic kernel (6.5.0-14).  But I can't even get the unpatched version to build.  It seems like I haven't got my Rust installation right but I can't figure out why.

So far I've removed the cargo directories from my `$PATH` and then done this:

```
$ sudo apt install rustc-1.68 bindgen-0.56 build-dep libncurses-dev gawk flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf llvm
$ apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
$ cd linux-6.5.0
$ fakeroot debian/rules clean
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-generic
```

This last one fails with:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/debian/build/build-generic'
***
*** Running 'bindgen-0.56' to check the libclang version (used by the Rust
*** bindings generator) failed with code 101. This may be caused by
*** a failure to locate libclang. See output and docs below for details:
***
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libclang: "couldn't find any valid shared libraries matching: ['libclang.so', 'libclang-*.so', 'libclang.so.*', 'libclang-*.so.*'], set the `LIBCLANG_PATH` environment variable to a path where one of these files can be found (invalid: [])"', src/lib.rs:1922:31
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
***
make[3]: *** [/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/Makefile:1833: rustavailable] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/tkcook/linux-6.5.0/debian/build/build-generic'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
```

The error message there suggests setting `LIBCLANG_PATH` to the location of libclang.so.1 but doing so (setting it to either `/usr/lib/llvm-17/lib` or `/usr/lib/llvm-17/lib/libclang.so.1`) doesn't make any difference, I suspect because either `fakeroot` or `debian/rules` is clobbering the setting.

Can someone point me to how to make this work?

Comment: Have you installed `libclang-dev` from universe repository?

Comment: Yes, it is at `1:16.0-57`.